# Change IME Option of Edittext in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am working on a Learning app, it has a Tabview so I'm working with Fragments.
The last fragment has buttons on top to navigate through the multiple levels. Below that there is a Recyclerview which contains a Cardview with a Question on the left and an Edittext on the right to answer.
Currently the IME Option is actionSend and I want to not only skip to the next Edittext but also evaluate the Answer that was given. I achieved this already by implementing an OnClickListener but it's quite annoying having to click each Cardview in the Recyclerview to get Feedback, so I want to copy it to the setOnEditorActionListener function for the Editext. The problem I have is that I don't know how to get the position of the current Cardview item (to evaluate the givenAnswer with the corresponding item in the Questionlist) in the Recyclerview without actually clicking it just by changing the Editext.

```
private RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
private ArrayList<Question> QuestionList;
private QuestionAdapter recyclerAdapter;
private EditText givenAnswer;

public void ClickManager(final ArrayList<Question> list){
        //works perfectly when the item is clicked
        recyclerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new QuestionAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final int position) {
                View itemView = myrecyclerview.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
                final EditText givenAnswer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answer);
                ClickEvaluation(list,givenAnswer,position);
            }
        });

        givenAnswer.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                boolean handled = false;
                if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND){
                    ClickEvaluation(list,givenAnswer,position); //can't access any position
                    handled = true;
                }

                return handled;
            }
        });
    }
```

The evaluation function:

```
public void ClickEvaluation(final ArrayList<Question> list, EditText givenAnswer, int position){

    Question currenQuestion = list.get(position);
    if (currenQuestion.correct(givenAnswer.getText().toString())){
        currenQuestion.gaveCorrectAnswer();
        score += 1;
        current.setText(String.format("%d",score));
    }else{
        currenQuestion.showCorrectAnswer();
    }
    givenAnswer.setText("");
    recyclerAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!